# PowerShell Catch exception one by one

Tags: powershell

I have a litle issue in my script, that I can't figure out.

```
$archiveHanldesSessionNames = @{}

try {
    foreach ($sourceContent in $SrcContent) {
        $archiveHanldesSessionNames.Add ($sourceContent.METATRANSCRIPT.ArchiveHandle, $sourceContent.METATRANSCRIPT.Session.Name)
    }
} catch [System.ArgumentNullException] {
    Write-Host " Warning!! ArchiveHandle not exists in:" -ForegroundColor Yellow `n`n "-"
    $sourceContent.METATRANSCRIPT.Session.Title
}
```

The output:

> Warning!! ArchiveHandle not exists in:
>
> - Conversation between Amparo and Juana in El Carbon

But should give me

> - Conversation between Amparo and Juana in El Carbon
> - xpto
> - xpti

It's working fine, but I need to catch all exceptions and make something else for each one.

Basically I'm adding values into a array, and if node note exists it gives me an exception `[System.ArgumentNullException]`.
My code catch the exception, and show-me the file that is missing that info, but I know there it exists at least one more. It finds only the first.

How can I do to all files that are included in that exception?

They are all in same directory.

Comment: put your try catch _inside_ your loop.

Comment: Thanks, so simple. Now it´s working fine